# Why does django open with pype?

Tags: python, windows, django

when i type in the command prompt

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

the django-admin.py will open automatically with pype,

now if i type `cd mysite` it says `the system cannot find the path specified`

I'm using activepython (i don't think that activepython has anything to do with it), django installed using pypm. I can create a project in pydev, not in the command prompt, about a year ago when i first installed activepython, it used to work but as far as i can remember i deleted a django project and it won't work anymore.

how to fix it?

**EDIT**

@Mikko Ohtamaa
 mysite folder does not exist,i see on pype that it has opened the file from `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Python\Scripts\django-admin.py`

but the path is incorrect i don't have an application data folder in `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\`

I have searched the entire pc and haven't find a folder, furthermore in you run this 100 times

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

it will keep opening a file called django-admin.py you know, nothing else

Comment: Use dir command or Windows Explorer to check whether it creates the mysite folder or not?

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but the path is incorrect i don't have an application data folder in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\"

This would mean that your Python or Django installation is corrupted (probably due to reinstall Python).

Try go to square zero and reinstall both Python and Djangon on your computer. Also if it still does not work please describe how did you install both of them.

Comment: actually sir, last month i uninstalled activepython and installed a newer version so still didn't work and i install django from pypm by writting pypm install django, it should be automatically installed...i think that there's something wrong with my computer, i mean why would django-admin.py open automatically with pype? i don't understand it :)

Comment: sir i started over as u said, see this question, i started a bounty on it because I only received 1 answer and it sucks!! http://bit.ly/pTSSyY