# If django is installed using pypm, would pydev detect it?

Tags: python, django, activepython, pypm

[i have recently asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206762/why-does-django-open-with-pype)

I rechecked and it seems that pydev does not detect django either, but i can import django in activepython interpreter. so if i installed django using pypm would pydev detect it?

Comment: You can install Django *globally* if the user-site path (which is where pypm installs into) is not recognized by pydev: `pypm -g install django`

Comment: @Sridhar Ratnakumar thank you so much sir, i have fixed this issue this afternoon, what i did is in the window preferences i pointed pydev to the site packages...this has been a complete headache for me, some told me to uninstall django, the others told me to uninstall python...i didn't even need to uninstall django...i wish you where here yesterday to save me from all of this :D

Comment: look at the theories man http://bit.ly/pg73m6 and the problem is silly yet i wouldn't have received a good answer if i haven't started a bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev currently doesn't pick additions to the PYTHONPATH automatically, so, you have to re-configure your interpreter within PyDev (even if only the PYTHONPATH changed).

See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

Comment: sir I tried to change the path didn't work, so since i have another problem with django as described in the question, I wounder if i uninstalled activepython django and installed django using pip would it work, and how about keeping the current django and installed a 2nd one?

Comment: Adding a 2nd one should be OK (you can have many at the same time). Still, not recognizing is strange... You should check if your PYTHONPATH is really correct (i.e.: the folder on the PYTHONPATH should be something as /mypath, considering that django is in /mypath/django/__init__.py).

Comment: Another thing, make sure that django is not installed as a zip file (i.e.: its contents should be uncompressed). If that still doesn't work, it may be that there's some problem in some internal cache (in that case you can try restarting Eclipse after configuring the shell).

Comment: would you check this question sir http://bit.ly/oKQjFc this exacly what's happening when running the django setup